# there is a way to put imagen from a .zip in a html?

Tags: javascript, html

I only know very little of html, and I have a little html file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            img { 
                max-width:100%; 
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div align="center">
            <p>test_img</p><img src="picture.gif" alt="my_img" >
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

my question is: if I have `picture.gif` inside a compressed `.zip` or `.rar` file in the same folder, say `my_imgs.zip`, there is a way to display that imagen in the html without extracting that imagen?? or that is no posible?

Comment: To get the original file you need to extract the file in one way or another. It is compressed so the file doesn't actually exist inside the zip file, the zip only contains the data required to reconstruct the file.

Comment: Why do you need such feature?

Comment: @JuanMendes I want to display in a nice html some img from some comic that I have, like is done in pag http://mangapark.me/ and I would like to avoid extracting them

Comment: Why do you want to avoid extracting them? Put them in a folder just for that purpose and forget about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer, no. You would have to extract the image (unzip the file) before you could reference it.

Comment: You could unpack the zip file in memory, e.g., `/path/file.zip/folder/file.png`. You'd implement that  yourself

Comment: But can you do that with only html itself? @JuanMendes

Comment: No, I missed the part about HTML alone, I'm still not sure it's really a requirement, it's unclear what the OP is trying to do